# IBM Watson IoT Rules: delayed triggering of actions

Tags: ibm-cloud, mqtt, iot, watson-iot

I have a simple rule setup which checks the temperature sensor value in the event data to be greater than 30 Celsius and trigger a NodeRed flow as an action. I see that there is delay in triggering the action. The delay I saw was around a minute to half an hour. Is this something to do with the QoS level of the event data messages being sent?

Comment: Are you using the real-time insight rules in the Watson IoT platform?  If so, you should not be seeing a delay.  Can you provide more details so we can help troubleshoot?

Comment: I have not created any Real time Insights service in Bluemix. I have configured the rules in the Watson IoT Platform.

Comment: Real time insights rules, actions, message schema configurations have been merged into the IBM Watson IoT platform

Comment: Hi I've forwarded this thread to the lab...let's see...